# How to Read all Records or Message of NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc

I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/luixal/5768921) to Read NFC tag...

So Here I am getting NFC tag ID which is Record[0]
by using  `ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID))`

I the similar way I want to Read NFC Record 1,Record 2,Record[3] like that
or NFC message..  `NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES`

Here only one tag is reading I want to get for multiple records of tags

Can any one suggest me on this kind....

Comment: You gave people who tried to help you 3 separate links to read just to understand your intent. Not all people have that much time on their hands. Try to explain as thorough as possible yet in a short, pleasant-to-read manner. Put some time into your questions and then maybe people would put theirs to answer it.

Comment: They are not three links actually I tried 1st one.. is only one which is showing output of All nfc tags. and 2nd one is reading only NfcA tag only so I followed 1st one...

Comment: I tried. There are 3 links. 2 pointed to a same resource but there are still 3 of them. Any reader won't have a clue about it since you didn't put any explanation. But I digress. I see you've updated your answer but to me, it's still don't explain your problem very well. Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page on how to ask a good question.

Comment: ho ok @ridsatrio Sir, Please check my Updated question... please send me any reference links regarding NFC...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read NDEF Msg and Records of NFC tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306020/how-to-read-ndef-msg-and-records-of-nfc-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's lot of tutorials on web, a simple search gave you this kind of code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef == null) {
                // NDEF is not supported by this Tag. 
                return;
            }
            NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();

            NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
            for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
                //read each record
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello sir I am using this....  `if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {` if I use Above code I what is Ndef.get(tag) tag...

Comment: Can You please set ur code in [this link](https://gist.github.com/luixal/5768921) I am using Second program.. I am confused with tag... at your code...

Comment: @Don'tBenegative sorry I don't understand, in your question you said "I want to get for multiple records of tags" it seems you want to read NDEFRecord, so I don't understand why you talk about ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED. Please read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

Comment: Sorry for Confusion I Used your code but Its not working In the above link second program... can you please explain...

Comment: Thanks for answer on both cases... I have Upvoted your answer please up vote my both questions..