# How to read NDEF Msg and Records of NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I am Working with Reading NDEF Msg and Records

Here I have done with Reading ID by using this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// list of NFC technologies detected:
private final String[][] techList = new String[][] {
        new String[] {
            NfcA.class.getName(),
            NfcB.class.getName(),
            NfcF.class.getName(),
            NfcV.class.getName(),
            IsoDep.class.getName(),
            MifareClassic.class.getName(),
            MifareUltralight.class.getName(), Ndef.class.getName()
        }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // creating pending intent:
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    // creating intent receiver for NFC events:
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    // enabling foreground dispatch for getting intent from NFC event:
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, new IntentFilter[]{filter}, this.techList);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // disabling foreground dispatch:
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) || intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED) || intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(
                "NFC Tag\n" + 
                ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)));
    }
}

private String ByteArrayToHexString(byte [] inarray) {
    int i, j, in;
    String [] hex = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
    String out= "";

    for(j = 0 ; j < inarray.length ; ++j) 
        {
        in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
        i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        i = in & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        }
    return out;
  }
 }
```

Here Reading Tag ID which is Record[0]

In the Similar way I want to Read NDEF msg and Records both in the same Program and Same way... We have many ways

Here I have tried with

```
    if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)) {
           Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef == null) {
                // NDEF is not supported by this Tag. 
                return;
            }
            NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();

            NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
            for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
                //read each record
            }
```

But I am Unable to read Records.. can any one suggest me to Read NDEF msg and records in my code....

**Update**

I have added this at manifest..

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    *<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>*
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
     <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

But Still I need to go with `NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES` can any one tell me How to use it in my code with out effecting or changing `NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID`.

Comment: Does your tag contain an NDEF message that could possibly be read with the above code? Is your tag an NFC Forum tag (i.e. a tag that is capable of containing an NDEF message)?

Comment: Yes I have Inserted nearly 4 records in NFC tag and I can Able to read them NFC reader Apps available in playstore. I think I need to use `NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES` or some thing else can any one tell me how to use in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add log to understand what happens.
2. Get `NDEFMessage` from tag in `Intent`
3. Your function to convert ByteArray to Hex string is not the best

And please read official documentation, all you need is explained:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#obtain-info

In your Activity, method onNewIntent:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent action=" + intent.getAction());
    if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) || intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED) || intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)) {

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(
                "NFC Tag\n" + 
                byteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)));
    }
    if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                NdefMessage ndefMessage = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
                for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
                    //read each record
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * convert byte array to a hexadecimal string
 *
 * @param bArray
 *            byte array to convert
 * @return hexadecimal string
 */
public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] bArray) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    for (byte b : bArray) {
        buffer.append(byteToHexString(b));
        buffer.append(" ");
    }

    return buffer.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
}

/**
 * convert byte to a hexadecimal string
 *
 * @param b
 *            byte to convert
 * @return hexadecimal string
 */
public static String byteToHexString(byte b) {

    int tmp = b & 0xFF;

    if (tmp <= 15) {
        return "0".concat(Integer.toHexString(tmp));
    } else {
        return Integer.toHexString(tmp);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sir may I know where is out put for msg for Id its ok... but for output i wan to use set text... Here i am using all techs of nfc tags so it should require all like ndef,techdiscovered,tag discoverd...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment